# Vaadin Select dropdown values continue to show after the form is closed?

Tags: vaadin

I have a simple Vaadin Form with a Select dropdown box on it. There is a Cancel button which closes the form when clicked. Alternatively, typing Escape triggers the Cancel button as well.

Everything works fine.
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzg5x.jpg)
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksqp2.jpg)

However, if I type the Escape key when the Select dropdown is active and showing all the possible values, the form closes but the list of dropdown values stays displayed;
[Image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYKPA.jpg)

Is there a way to close the Select manually, as part of the Cancel call?

Comment: I think you have possibly found a bug that has not been documented yet. Can you create a simplified demo code that replicates the issue and report it in Vaadin's component issue tracker https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/issues